# Knockout binding Object issue

Tags: typescript, knockout.js

When i run the program, the values returned from controller are not showing on page. I used debugger and found values are being returned from controller but nothing shown up on page.

[image]
AboutController.cs

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public About AboutDetais()
{
    About about = new About();
    about.CompanyName = "Hashoo";
    about.Phone = "123455";

    return about;
}

public class About
{

    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }

}
```

about.ts

```
import * as ko from 'knockout';
import 'isomorphic-fetch';

interface AboutModel {
    companyName: string;
    phone: string;
}

class AboutPageViewModel {
    public aboutModel = ko.observable<AboutModel>();

    constructor() {

        fetch('api/About/AboutDetais')
            .then(response => response.json() as Promise<AboutModel>)
            .then(data => {
                this.aboutModel(data);
            });
    }
}

export default { viewModel: AboutPageViewModel, template: require('./about.html') };
```

about.html

```
<p>This is a simple example of a Knockout component</p>

<p>Company Namne: </p> <p data-bind="text: aboutModel.companyName"></p>
<p>Phone: </p> <p data-bind="text: aboutModel.phone"></p>
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? Also, `data.companyName` should be `aboutModel.companyName`

Comment: Yes it should be aboutModel.companyName. i was just playing around to see. Still it showing nothing. No error in console.

Comment: Is there a `ko.applyBindings(new viewModel())` somewhere in your code?

Comment: @adiga I am using dotnet new knockout (SPA template). So i believe it must be somewhere because other default pages are working.  (Weatherforcast etc)

Comment: Try `aboutModel().companyName`